# Get user administrating pages on googleplus/mybusiness

Tags: api, google-plus, google-places-api

I would like that users come to my website, log in with their google account and show the pages that their managing on google plus.

In facts i would like to get the google plus page automatically created by Mybusiness when they signup their business.

At this time i dont know which api use. I find nothing on google plus api and the mybusiness api needs me to be whitelisted but i dont know if it worth it because i cant find if it gives what i need.

Any idea ?

Useful links : 
https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/get-started#request_access_to_the_api

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/plus/v1/